# Error creating SQL Alchemy Association Table

Tags: python, mysql, json, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Im back with another SQL Alchemy error for you all. Im not sure why I'm struggling so much with their documentation or if i'm just too dumb to understand but hopefully someone is willing to help me out.

I am currently trying to create a many-to-many relationship between two tables; Dataset_Table & Table_Table (ignore the weird names)

I have created the appropriate classes and added the association table with the appropriate params linking the two classes and their id's together.

```
t_dataset_table = Table(
't_dataset_table',
metadata,
Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
Column('dataset_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Dataset_Table.dataset_id'), nullable=False),
Column('table_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Table_Table.table_id'), nullable=False)
)


class Dataset_Table(Base):
__tablename__ = 'dataset'

dataset_id = Column(INTEGER(10), primary_key=True)
dataset_name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
dataset_title = Column(String(45))
dataset_comment = Column(Text, nullable=False)
dataset_is_archived = Column(TINYINT(4), nullable=False, server_default=text("'0'"))
Dataset_date_created = Column(TIMESTAMP)

tables = relationship('Table_Table',
                      secondary=t_dataset_table,
                      back_populates='dataset')

class Table_Table(Base):
__tablename__ = 'table'

table_id = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key=True, unique=True)
table_group = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
table_name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
table_description = Column(Text, nullable=False)
table_longitudinal = Column(Enum('S', 'Y', 'N', 'L'))
table_medical_domains = Column(Enum('DERMATOLOGY', 'OPHTHALMOLOGY', 'ORTHOPEDICS', 'PLASTICS', 'ENT', 'GI', 'RHEUMATOLOGY', 'UROLOGY'))
table_is_archived = Column(TINYINT(4), nullable=False, server_default=text("'0'"))

datasets = relationship('Dataset_Table',
                        secondary=t_dataset_table,
                        back_populates='table')
```

I've create the association table and the two columns within each table to handle their 'children' (the `tables` column inside of Dataset_Table and the `dataset` column within Table_Table).

Am I missing anything else?

I am currently looping through some JSON data and pulling back the data by creating instances of the class and populating that instance.

```
with open("cow.json") as js:
    data = json.load(js)

 ds = Dataset_Table 
ds.dataset_comment = data['_comment']
    for tables in data['tables']:
        tb = Table_Table
        tb.table_name = tables['name']
```

For some reason I get an error when I try to append a table onto that dataset instance (ds) `ds.tables.append(tb)`

```
Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object 
associated with Dataset_Table.tables has an attribute 'append'
```

Im not sure if it's worth to mention that I the docs create instances of their classes by calling the Class ie `cow = Dataset_Table()` but I do that without parenthesis?

Is there a difference? Am I doing something completely wrong? Should I just give up and become a garbageman? You tell me.

Thank you so much for your time and help.

-- EDIT

The error I get when I try to create instances of my Dataset class ie: 
   `cow = Dataset_Table(dataset_name = 'cow table')`

is:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table' is not mapped
```

Comment: There's a huge difference, and it is something that you'll catch up with reading a good Python tutorial; `ds = Dataset_Table` simply binds the object (in this case a class) referenced by `Dataset_Table` to another name `ds`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thank you for this... Any idea as to why I get an error when I try to create that instance (with proper parenthesis)

Comment: It is hard to say without the traceback that goes with the error.